# Некорректное отображение цвета richtext в TextView из Html

Tags: android, spannable

С сервера получаю строку с html-разметкой и пытаюсь отобразить содержимое в TextView.

```
String value = "<HTML><BODY><P ALIGN=\"left\"><FONT FACE=\"OpenSans\" SIZE=\"12\" COLOR=\"#000000\" LETTERSPACING=\"0\" KERNING=\"0\"><I>Hi</I> <FONT COLOR=\"#cc6600\"><U>fd</U></FONT><U>sf</U> <FONT COLOR=\"#00cc33\"><I>hel</I></FONT><FONT SIZE=\"26\" COLOR=\"#00cc33\"><I>lo</I></FONT><B><I>e</I></B></FONT></P></BODY></HTML>"
Spanned spannedText = Html.fromHtml(value);
Spannable reversedText = revertSpanned(spannedText);
textView.setText(reversedText);

final Spannable revertSpanned(Spanned stext) {
    ParcelableSpan[] spans = stext.getSpans(0, stext.length(), ParcelableSpan.class);
    Spannable ret = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(stext.toString());
    if (spans != null && spans.length > 0) {
        for(int i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            ret.setSpan(spans[i], stext.getSpanStart(spans[i]), stext.getSpanEnd(spans[i]), stext.getSpanFlags(spans[i]));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

На Samsung SM-T560 (Android 4.4.4) и Google Pixel (Android 8.1.0) получаю следующий результат: [image: 1]. Но на Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1) результат: [image: 2], который меня не устраивает. Если на Nexus 5 не использовать функцию `revertSpanned` то данный пример будет отображаться корректно цветным. Похоже данная проблема будет на любом смартфоне с андроидом 6.0. Использовать/не использовать `revertSpanned` в зависимости от версии – не является решением, т.к. это решит проблему только в данном примере. Но у меня есть и другие примеры с html, в которых отображается часть цвета текста без `revertSpanned`, а другая часть отображается при использовании `revertSpanned`. Возможно проблема появляется и на других версиях андроида. Как ее решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потестировал, оказалось проблема с отображением вложенных тегов проявляется на Android с 6.0 по 7.1.1 включительно.
Решил ее путем дробления родительских `Span`-ов так, чтобы объекты одного стиля (в данном случае `ForegroundColorSpan`) не накладывались друг на друга.